# Angular: How to switch repository to download node_modules dependencies from internal company source

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have an internal company artifactory (repository) where all of the dependency libraries need to be installed from. I cannot download them from the internet when I do `npm install`.

I look inside the `package-lock.json` and I see that all the dependencies are there and it seems like it's using `registry.npmjs.org` like an example below.

```
"ngx-bootstrap": {
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-bootstrap/-/ngx-bootstrap-3.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-ni91yYtn8ldgf/pxrlwl9lkVcLURGzopSpJnEbbgG1v1EZWTobI8y7J3mx4Kxptkn0EeiQwnLel67G7XJSox4A=="
},
```

So, do I have to go through the entire `package-lock.json` file and replace the `registry.npmjs.org` with my company's internal repository? for example like below

```
"ngx-bootstrap": {
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://[mycompany.internal-artifactory.com]/ngx-bootstrap/-/ngx-bootstrap-3.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-ni91yYtn8ldgf/pxrlwl9lkVcLURGzopSpJnEbbgG1v1EZWTobI8y7J3mx4Kxptkn0EeiQwnLel67G7XJSox4A=="
},
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set information like this in your `.npmrc` file. This is the same as setting the value through the command line, but it's in a file for distribution and version control.

From the [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc):

> The four relevant files are:
>
> - per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
> - per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
> - global config file ($PREFIX/etc/npmrc)
> - npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)
>
> All npm config files are an ini-formatted list of key = value parameters. Environment variables can be replaced using ${VARIABLE_NAME}

In any of these files, depending on the scope of how you would like the registry setting to apply, you can simply place the below:

```
registry=https://[mycompany.internal-artifactory.com]
```

If you want this change to be global on your machine, modify `~/.npmrc`, as described in the documentation. I'd recommend modifying the `.npmrc` file in your project root so that other developers on your team do not need to make the same changes.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your global .npmrc file. The file location by default is usually C/Users/'Your name'/.npmrc. This is assuming your company allows you to modify this.

You can then change the registry location back to the default

`registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/`

If you want to change it to your company's repo, just change the registry URL to your company's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Get your company's package manger URL and then do a `set registry` command. It should then pull from your company's source when doing an `npm install`